# how to hack a real SD card in android emulator? (via USB card reader)

Tags: android, android-emulator, sd-card, android-sdcard

i know that emulator can create a sdcard.img as a device for emulator use.

but now, i want to use a real SD card in android emulator.
Is it possible that i build android emulator in windows environment or this request need to implement in Linux environment?

any idea is welcome.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I got the answer by myself...

first thing we occured in this issue is got below warning when execute emulator.

#### WARNING: SD Card files must be at least 9MB, ignoring /dev/sdX

after traced the source code in main.c,

```
   if (size < 9*1024*1024ULL) {
           fprintf(stderr, "### WARNING: SD Card files must be at least 9MB, ignoring '%s'\n", opts->sdcard);
        } else {
            hw->hw_sdCard_path = ASTRDUP(opts->sdcard);
        }
```

I ignored the if condition, i.e. force execute hw->hw_sdCard_path = ASTRDUP(opts->sdcard);

then, everything go right:)